# Generated Project Portfolio Timeline

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, gantt-chart, vba

I have a list of Projects:

> Project A
>   Project B
>   Project C

and milestones for each project with a date for the milestone:

> Project A    Milestone 1     01/01/2015
>   Project A    Milestone 2     01/02/2015
>   Project A    Milestone 3     01/03/2015
>   Project B    Milestone 1     01/04/2015

I am looking to generate a type of timeline for all of the projects in one sheet, with milestones displayed in their respective month.

Column A would have the list of projects and row 1 have months, then to display the milestone where the month and project match.

So far I have been able to extract the list of projects using a macro:

```
Sub UniqueList()
Dim rListPaste As Range
Dim iReply As Integer

On Error Resume Next

Set rListPaste = Application.InputBox _
(Prompt:="Please select the destination cell", Type:=8)

    If rListPaste Is Nothing Then
       iReply = MsgBox("No range nominated," _
          & " terminate", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)
      If iReply = vbYes Then Exit Sub
    End If

   Range("A1", Range("A65536").End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter _
   Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=rListPaste.Cells(1, 1), Unique:=True

End Sub
```

After this I am pretty stuck. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So your projects are in column A, your milestones are in column B, and your dates are in column C, correct?

Comment: Were you able to use the code below?

Answer (score 0):

I've done a similar setup to develop a milestone chart based on the current week. I've modified it to match your requirements:

```
Sub CreateMilestoneChart()

Dim ws1         As Worksheet
Dim ws2         As Worksheet
Dim LastRow     As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim FirstMonth  As Long
Dim FirstYear   As Long
Dim LastMonth   As Long
Dim LastYear    As Long
Dim curRange    As Range

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Project List")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Milestone Chart")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

LastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'-----You will want to modify or remove these lines once-----
'-----you get the sheet formatted the way you want-----------
ws2.Cells.Clear
ws2.Range("A1").Value = "Milestone Chart"
ws2.Range("A2").Value = "Generated on " & Date
ws2.Range("A3").Value = "Month:"
ws2.Range("A3").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
'------------------------------------------------------------

ws1.Range("A1:C" & LastRow).Copy
ws2.Range("A4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
    , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

LastRow = LastRow + 3
For i = 4 To LastRow
    ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & ws2.Cells(i, 2).Value
Next i
ws2.Range("A4:A" & LastRow).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
ws2.Range("B4:B" & LastRow).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
With ws2.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B4:B" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SetRange Range("A4:B" & LastRow)
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

FirstMonth = DatePart("m", ws2.Range("B4").Value)
FirstYear = DatePart("yyyy", ws2.Range("B4").Value)
LastMonth = DatePart("m", ws2.Range("B" & LastRow).Value)
LastYear = DatePart("yyyy", ws2.Range("B" & LastRow).Value)

ws2.Range("B3").Value = CDate(FirstMonth & "/" & FirstYear)
Set curRange = ws2.Range("B3")
i = 1
Do Until DatePart("m", curRange.Value) = LastMonth And DatePart("yyyy", curRange.Value) = LastYear
    Set curRange = ws2.Cells(3, i + 2)
    curRange.Value = DateAdd("m", 1, ws2.Cells(3, i + 1).Value)
    i = i + 1
Loop
ws2.Cells(3, i + 2).Value = DateAdd("m", 1, ws2.Cells(3, i + 1).Value)

For i = 4 To LastRow
    j = 2
    Do Until ws2.Cells(i, j).Value >= ws2.Cells(3, j).Value And ws2.Cells(i, j).Value < ws2.Cells(3, j + 1).Value
        ws2.Cells(i, 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        ws2.Cells(i, 2).Value = "'-----------------"
        j = j + 1
    Loop
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

It's not very clean by any means, but it will work. You will need to modify it to fit your needs.